# Finding a linear model with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

#### Problem

Brand Z's annual sales are affected by the sales of related products X and Y as follows:

- Each $\$1 $ million increase in sales of brand X causes a $\$2.1$ million decline in sales of brand Z, whereas each $\$2$ million increase in sales of brand Y results in an increase of $\$23$ million in sales of brand Z.
- Currently, brands X and Y are selling $\$2$ million per year and brand Z is selling $\$62$ million a year.

Model the sales of brand Z using a linear function. (Let z = annual sales of Z (in millions of dollars), x = annual sales of X (in millions of dollars), and y = annual sales of Y (in millions of dollars).)

#### Progress

I have been staring at it for awhile and have came up with nothing that's correct. Tried $z(x,y)=11.5y-2.1x$ but that was wrong.

Comment: Seems straight forward.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been staring at it for awhile and have came up with nothing thats correct. tried z(x,y)=11.5y-2.1x but that was wrong.

Comment: Try $z(x,y)= 11.5 y-2.1 x + C$, then use the current values to find $C$.

Comment: Thanks alot man! I think I have the right answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear relationship is: $ z(x,y) = A x + B y + C$

Use the second paragraph to determine the constants $A$ and $B$. Hint: $\Delta z = A \Delta x + B \Delta y$.

Use the current values, $x_0, y_0, z_0$ to determine the constant $C$.  Hint: $z_0 = z(x_0,y_0)$